# Format text to CSV

Tags: powershell

I want to convert into csv like

```
Far   intVer RelVer
Naka  10.9   18.9
Paka  NA     NA
Moka  10.8   17.8
Sota  NA     NA
Kata  10.9  12.6
```

From input txt file

```
Far=naka
IntVer=10.9
RelVer=18.9
Far=paka
Far=moka
IntVer=10.8
RelVer=17.8
Far=sota
Far=kata
IntVer=10.9
RelVer=12.6
```

How to convert input text file to Excel or csv  using powershell only

Comment: What code have you written so far? What worked? What didn’t work? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to improve your chances of getting help…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your txt file only contains usable data, this should work:

```
function FormatCsv {

    Param (
        [string]$CsvFile
    )    

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($CsvFile)) {
        throw [System.ArgumentNullException]::new('CsvFile cannot not be null or empty.');
    }
    [string[]]$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($CsvFile)
    if ($content.Length -lt 1) {
        return [string]::Empty;
    }

    [string]$COLUMN_FAR = 'Far';
    [string]$COLUMN_INTVER = 'IntVer';
    [string]$COLUMN_RELVER = 'RelVer';

    [bool]$entryStart = $false;

    $entries = @();
    [string]$farTemp = '';
    [double]$intTemp = 0.0d;
    [double]$relTemp = 0.0d;

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Length; $i++) {
        [string]$current = $content[$i];
        if ($current.StartsWith($COLUMN_FAR)) {
            if ($entryStart) {                
                $entryTemplate = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Far = $farTemp
                    IntVer = $intTemp
                    RelVer = $relTemp
                };
                $entries += $entryTemplate;
                $farTemp = [string]::Empty;
                $intTemp = 0.0d;
                $relTemp = 0.0d;
            }
            $entryStart = $true;
            [int]$assignPos = $current.IndexOf('=');
            if ($assignPos -gt 0) {
                $assignPos += 1;
                $farTemp = $current.Substring($assignPos, $current.Length - $assignPos);
            }            
            continue;
        }
        elseif ($current.StartsWith($COLUMN_INTVER)) {
            [int]$assignPos = $current.IndexOf('=');
            if ($assignPos -gt 0) {
                $assignPos += 1;
                [double]$d = 0;
                [string]$temp = $current.Substring($assignPos, $current.Length - $assignPos);                
                $intTemp = [double]::Parse($temp, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture);
            }
            continue;
        }
        elseif ($current.StartsWith($COLUMN_RELVER)) {
            [int]$assignPos = $current.IndexOf('=');
            if ($assignPos -gt 0) {
                $assignPos += 1;
                [double]$d;
                [string]$temp = $current.Substring($assignPos, $current.Length - $assignPos);
                $relTemp = [double]::Parse($temp, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture);
            }
            continue;
        }        
    }
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($farTemp)) {
        $entryTemplate = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Far = $farTemp
            IntVer = $intTemp
            RelVer = $relTemp
        };
        $entries += $entryTemplate;
        $farTemp = [string]::Empty;
        $intTemp = 0.0d;
        $relTemp = 0.0d;
    }
    return $entries;
    
}

FormatCsv -CsvFile 'c:\file\path\my.csv' | ft
```